# Docker on windows: data in mounted volume doesn't updated

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I run docker on windows 10 with this command:

```
docker run -d -v /c/Users/tsh/docker:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 nginx
```

Inside **Users/tsh/docker** folder I have simple **index.html** file:

```
<h1>Hello!</h1>
```

It works perfectly well, when I point my browser on windows to virtualbox IP I can see web page with "Hello!" displayed.
But when I change content of the **index.html** to something like:

```
<h1>Hello from docker!</h1>
```

The web page still shows me the old "Hello!" text.

Is it possible when I change **index.html** data on the web page is also changed?

---

Upd:

```
docker run -it -v //c/Users/tsh/docker:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 nginx bash
root@ae5fc6b6126a:/# cd /usr/share/nginx/html
root@ae5fc6b6126a:/usr/share/nginx/html# cat index.html
<h1>Hello from docker!</h1>
root@ae5fc6b6126a:/usr/share/nginx/html#
```

Container see new data `<h1>Hello from docker!</h1>` but page still shows the old **Hello!**

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears to be related to Virtualbox caching. I also encountered [this problem recently editing CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691388/docker-error-css-file-in-mapped-volume-fails-to-update) and I was able to create a "workaround" by resetting the image in Virtualbox.  But, I call this a workaround only in a vague sense since it is not very useful to have to completely reboot the boot2docker image each time you make an edit to an HTML doc.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issues with the windows paths. Please try the workaround suggested in Github issue https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12590

Use double leading slashes on the path:

`docker run -d -v --name mynginx //c/Users/tsh/docker:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 nginx`

**You can debug your situation as follows:**
First name your container as 'mynginx' using the above updated run command

Then you can enter into the container using following command:
`docker exec -it mynginx /bin/bash`

Now you should be inside the container, and there you can verify the contents of the mounted file using:

`cat /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`

If the file here is showing your changes, and still your browser is showing the old file, that means the file is cached somewhere in the chain. Nginx / browser. If it is cached in the browser, you can check by opening in the incognito window or doing Ctrl + F5.

Comment: Problem still exist.
Even if I change, file and restart container web page is still shown the old text which was before container relaunch(

Comment: Can you enter the container and check if the change is visible? Updated the answer with steps

Comment: Change is visible inside the container, but firefox in private mode still shows old text. When I tested this solution I discover strange behavior, if I have this in my **index.html**:
`<h1>Hello from docker!</h1>`
In browser I have: **Hello from docker!** as expected. But when I change **index.html** to:
`<h1>Hello </h1>`
In browser I have: **Hello from**
There is definitely some caching going on, but where and how can I disable it?

Comment: Try changing the file from within the container using vi editor. If the changes are reflecting, then there is something to do with docker and windows interoperability. If the changes are not visible in browser then your browser caching be doubted. It could as well be from nginx, but I seriously doubt nginx not respecting changed files.

Comment: Thank you, changing file from within the container, visible in browser. Do you know what in windows can causing the trouble?

Comment: I couldn't guess the problem as I never used docker directly within Windows, but I could ask you to try running the container with administrator privileges (from a command prompt / powershell with administrator privileges. You may also try adding ` --privileged `to the docker run command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with Apache. VirtualBox on Windows and Centos with httpd and php on docker. Problem fixed by changing **httpd.conf** parameter

```
#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults if commented: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off
```

**EnableSendfile** to **off** because

> ...but must be turned off when serving from networked-mounted filesystems...

Sending files still works good. Hope this will help someone.