# Docker Error: CSS File in Mapped Volume Fails to Update

Tags: caching, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

**System Setup:**

- Docker Version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
- Oracle VirtualBox 4.3.34r104062
- Image: https://hub.docker.com/r/rc42/flaskserver/

When I edit the CSS file in my flask server `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/bootstrap.css') }}">`, the following things seem to happen:

1. The changes do not show up when I reload the localhost test page.
2. The changes do not show up when I remove/rerun the container.
3. The changes do not show up when I stop/restart the container.

At first, I thought it might be a web browser cache problem, but it is not. I have tested this problem against a hard reload, different browsers and all manner of browser cache clearing.  On top of this, when I enter the container and examine the file, none of the changes show up in a 'cat' or 'grep' call. But, all examinations of the file on my own system show the changes have indeed occurred on the file.

The only way that I can seem to get these changes to propagate is if I refactor the file name to a name I have not previously used for the css file. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/bootstrap1.css') }}">` But, if I refactor the name back to the original name, the old version of the file once again shows up in my cat commands and file requests.

**PROBLEM: VIRTUALBOX MEMORY**
I do not know exactly what is happening, but this seems to be some caching problem with VirtualBox. On a hunch, I "Reset" the boot2docker image in Virtualbox and the latest changes that I made to the file prior to the reset propagated.

But, there does not appear to be any way to adjust Virtualbox to prevent this caching problem from occurring. "Use Host I/O Cache" toggle is permanently set to ON in the Settings > Storage for the image.

Perhaps the guys at Docker can look into this. It sounds like there is some memory management problem that isn't just isolated to my case. A similar problem has also been [documented recently here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187859/docker-on-windows-data-in-mounted-volume-doesnt-updated) by someone performing web app edits through Virtualbox. And, it doesn't seem to be very useful for editing to have to reset Virtualbox every time I make a style change.

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Virtualbox's shared filesystem has some issues with sendfile, which is probably what your http server config is using here. If you turn off sendfile I suspect this will work as expected.