# Docker reload does not reflect changes in CSS files

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

I've configured docker to reload automatically when i make changes to my project files. It works fine when i make changes in HTML or .py files but does not reflect any changes to CSS files. this question has also been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691388/docker-error-css-file-in-mapped-volume-fails-to-update) but there is no answer yet. Please help!

I'm using Flask python with gunicorn. Exactly following [this](https://www.udemy.com/the-build-a-saas-app-with-flask-course/) course on udemy.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Hi Hasan, I learned that this error is erratic in nature. The simplest fix i found was to run another parallel application which apparently resets virtualbox ( used by docker ). Clearing cache after doing that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Figured that this error is unpredictable. Its a problem with virtualbox used by Docker. The simplest workaround i found was to run another parallel application which apparently resets virtualbox. Clearing browser cache after doing that solved the problem for me.

While this is just a workaround, if anyone has a clear solution, please share it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem [and solved it using this suggestion by @famelis:](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1054#issuecomment-317487143)

> The problem, IMHO, is with the browser. It is using the cache for css and js.
>   If you are in development environment you can use google chrome and open the programmer's tools (Ctrl+Shift+I)
>   Then in the Network tab the "Disable cache" must be checked, and this solves the problem.
>   In production you need to have different paths/names for the files, possibly with version number, for the browser to re-read the files and not use the cache.